# Not Receiving Responses until request completes execution loop in python streaming request

Tags: python, json, rest, response

I am trying to achieve streaming in python. i have a requirement to return huge result from cursor to rest api. i am using flask stream_with_context while returning responses. but when i try requesting using stream=True flag my request wait for responses till cursor executes all the data.

expecting to receive 1 to 10 elements one by one when gets yield in response. but my requestor from test.py waits until all elemnst are processed from service_runner.py

here are the code sample.
service_runner.py

```
from flask import Flask, stream_with_context, Response
import time, json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/StreamData')
def StreamData():
    def stream1():
        for i in range(10):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1) # this is to see requestor recives stream or not.
            yield json.dumps(i)
    return Response(stream_with_context(stream1()))
```

test.py

```
import requests, asyncio, aiohttp
URL='http://127.0.0.1:5000/StreamData'
def TestStream():
    req1 = requests.get(URL, stream=True)
    print(req1)
    for r in req1.iter_lines(chunk_size=1):
        print(r)

async def TestWithAsync():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(URL) as resp:
            print(await resp.content.read())

def main():
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(TestWithAsync())
    event_loop.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    TestStream()
    main()
```